# How to assign non-linear regression output parameter to a variable

Tags: r, variables, parameters, variable-assignment, non-linear-regression

I would like to use the parameters estimated by the nls function

I am performing a non linear regression on data using the `m1<-nls(y1~v1*x/(k1+x))` function.
I can display the predicted v1 and k1 values that are stored in m1.
How can I assign these values to a specific variable (sort of "parameter <- v1")?
v1 and k1 object do not exist ("Error: object 'v1' not found")

```
>\> m1<-nls(y1~v1*x/(k1+x))

>\> m1

> Nonlinear regression model
>  model: y1 ~ v1 * x/(k1 + x)

>   data: parent.frame()

>   v1    k1 

> 16.83 30.05 

> residual sum-of-squares: 0.8571

> Number of iterations to convergence: 5

> Achieved convergence tolerance: 1.4e-06

>\> parameter <- v1
>
Error: object 'v1' not found
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This gives a vector of coefficients

```
co <- coef(m1)
```

and this gives them individually:

```
v1 <- coef(m1)[["v1"]]
k1 <- coef(m1)[["k1"]]
```

or if you just want to compute an expression using the coefficients:

```
with(as.list(coef(m1)), k1 + v1)
```

This would work to copy all individual elements of `coef(m1)` to your workspace:

```
list2env(as.list(coef(m1)), .GlobalEnv)
```